# XSLT Copy parent attribute to lower level

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT, so this might be basic, but I would really appreciate some input. I need to copy a parent tag value to a lower node and also replace the value of the child tag.

So my initial XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Header>
    <expand>names,schema</expand>
    <total>579</total>
    <maxResults>1</maxResults>
    <issues>
        <expand>test1</expand>
        <self>test2</self>
        <id>19988</id>
        <fields>
            <summary>Getting error when trying to complete Return Item Processing in FBCDAT</summary>
            <issuetype>
                <name>Functionality</name>
                <self>abc</self>
                <description>An issue within the functionality</description>
                <id>9</id>
            </issuetype>
        </fields>
    </issues>
</Header>
```

My requirement is ,

1. copy the `<id>19988</id>` to Fields level.
2. replace the `<id>9</id>` under `<issuetype>` with `<id>19988</id>`

So the Expected XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Header>
    <expand>names,schema</expand>
    <total>579</total>
    <maxResults>1</maxResults>
    <issues>
        <expand>test1</expand>
        <self>test2</self>
        <id>19988</id>
        <fields>
            <id>19988</id>
            <summary>Getting error when trying to complete Return Item Processing in FBCDAT</summary>
            <issuetype>
                <name>Functionality</name>
                <self>abc</self>
                <description>An issue within the functionality</description>
                <id>19988</id>
            </issuetype>
        </fields>
    </issues>
</Header>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off with the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To copy the `id` field to the `fields` element, you need a template matching `fields` that does the job...

```
<xsl:template match="fields">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../id" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And to replace the `id` under `issuetype`, have yet another template...

```
<xsl:template match="issuetype/id">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../../../id" />
</xsl:template>
```

Put this altogether gives this....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fields">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../id" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="issuetype/id">
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../../id" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tim, that's awesome! Worked. Thanks!